# XCode Number and its localized value

Tags: xcode, cocoa, random, nsdictionary

I'm making app with countries and it's flag. Now i have a problem. I have flags named from 1 to 200. And all names for numbers. (For example, 1 is Australia, 2 is USA). I use random to display flag in the `UIImageView`. After that i have 4 buttons, which become their names from flag name. 
All code in the end.

I have an array, where i store names of images.

- I have an array, where i store names of images.
- And a file with names for buttons.

And question: *How can I replace number of country with name?*
How to put in NSDictionary all names from file? Or what to do to have such functionality?

Sorry for my English. :)
Code for function, which makes nextFlag.

```
- (void)nextFlag
{
    int tmp = random() % [avalibleFlags count];
    NSString *imgString = [avalibleFlags objectAtIndex:tmp]; 
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imgString ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    currentFlagName = imgString;
    [_currentFlag setImage:newImage];
    [avalibleFlags removeObjectAtIndex:tmp];
    NSMutableArray *tmpFlags = [allFlags mutableCopy];
    [tmpFlags removeObjectAtIndex:tmp];
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) 
    {
        int tmpNumber = random() % [tmpFlags count];
        NSString *stringForButton = [tmpFlags objectAtIndex:tmpNumber];
        [tmpFlags removeObjectAtIndex:tmpNumber];
        [buttonNames insertObject:stringForButton atIndex:i];
    }
    int tmp2 = random() % 4;
    [[_buttons objectAtIndex:tmp2] setTitle:imgString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i<4; i++) {
        if ([[_buttons objectAtIndex:i] currentTitle] != currentFlagName) 
        {
            [[_buttons objectAtIndex:i] setTitle:[buttonNames objectAtIndex:j] forState:UIControlStateNormal];;
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to map a number to the country name just map the image name to the country name. This way the exact order is not critical. This is going to be easiest to manage in a file and as you mention the names really should be localized. So you want to use a special table of localized strings that map file names to country names. A convenient way to do this is `NSLocalizedStringFromTable()`. To retrieve the country name for a particular flag in your program you would use:

```
NSString *countryName = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(imgString, @"FlagToCountry", @"");
```

Then in your Code project add a localized file to your project called "FlagToCountry.strings". It should  have all the flag to country mappings in the usual .strings file format like:

```
/* Australia */
"aus" = "Australia"

/* USA */
"usa" = "USA"
...
```